# What does the notation $U(\frak{g})[[\hbar]]$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, category-theory, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

I'm reading [the following motivation](http://webpages.math.luc.edu/%7Eptingley/oldseminars/QuantumGroupsSpring2011/lecture1.pdf) for studying quantum group but I'm unfamiliar with the double bracket notation in
$$U(\frak{g})[[\hbar]].$$
Is this a special set of polynomials with coefficient in the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: Very likely that's the formal power series ring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It denotes the formal power series ring with coefficients in the ring $U(\mathfrak{g})$.
This is explicitly explained in texts on quantum groups, e.g., on page $2$ in the article [Classification of quantum groups and
Belavin–Drinfeld cohomologies](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.4046).